# How to use timezones in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

The user creates date in format like as: `12/23/2016 22:10`
After this data should be sent convert to another timezone, for example `GMT + 2`:

`12/23/2016 00:10`

I can assume the date that I create should be saved in GTM 0, only after I can  change timezone.
How can I use this mechanism in Laravel?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Carbon`](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) to change the the timezone of a date as:

```
$date = Carbon\Carbon::parse('12/23/2016 22:10', 'GMT');
```

And to add +2 you can do as:

```
$date->addHours(2)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can change the timezone for your application in: /config/app.php,

The default timezone is UTC. You can find all supported timezones here: http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

Answer (score 2):

Mostly I'm agree with Amit Gupa answer, but the best way to manage timezone conversion isn't by adding hours, but by converting it on Carbon:

```
$yourdate->timezone('somecountrytimezone')
```

This way you won't have to worry about different time management between countries (Like daylight saving time) and just manage to get your works done.

Please refer do the documentation : http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-settersfluent

Answer (score 0):

We can use parse and createFromFormat methods of Carbon to set our datetime as a certain timezone then use setTimezone to convert it to another timezone.

```
$date = "2022-08-05 12:00:00"; //set datetime for checking
$now = Carbon::now()->timezone('Europe/London')->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$createFrom = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $date, 'Asia/Hong_Kong')->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$parse = Carbon::parse($date,'Asia/Hong_Kong')->setTimezone('Europe/London')->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$converted = Carbon::parse($date,'Asia/Hong_Kong')->timezone('Europe/London')->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

outputs: when dd($now,$createFrom,$parse,$converted);

```
^ "2022-08-05 08:33:48"

^ "2022-08-05 12:00:00"

^ "2022-08-05 05:00:00"

^ "2022-08-05 05:00:00"
```

Answer (score -2):

that's not related to laravel , it's just a php , so you can simply get the time-zone offset (exp GMT+3) then do like this :

$timeZoneOffset ---> for GMT+3 you put (3)

```
   function getNewDateByTimeZone($date, $timeZoneOffset)
    {
        /* if the client Time zone is GMT */
        if (!$timeZoneOffset || $timeZoneOffset == 0) {
            $timeZoneOffset = "-0";

        }

        $op = $timeZoneOffset[0];
        $timeZoneOffset = preg_replace('/[^0-9.]+/', '', $timeZoneOffset) * 60;
        $userDate = date($date, time());
        $timeStamp = strtotime($userDate);    

       $offsetTime = $op == '-' ? $timeStamp + $timeZoneOffset : $timeStamp - $timeZoneOffset;



        return date("Y-m-d H:i", $offsetTime);


    }
```

so like that you will save the date in GMT-0